# Как добавить HTTP заголовок авторизации

Tags: java, http, servlet, request

У меня проблема связанная с добавлением `HTTP` заголовка авторизации во все запросы к приложению. В приложени есть часть авторизации в котором я использую `JWT` токен. С помощью `AJAX` запроса я передаю реквизиты для входа `(email,password)`. Для валидацы этого запроса  и для создания  токена я использую `HttpFilter` фильтр. Как мне добавить в каждый `HTTP` запрос заголовок авторизации примерно так `Authorization Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ik......`  чтобы в перенапровленни все работало.

Заранне спасибо.

Вот код

AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#attempt").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/profile',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa($('#email').val() + ":" + $('#password').val())
            },
            success: function (response, status, request) {
               window.location="http://localhost:8080/profile";
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + "Fuck");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

JAVA code

```
package org.company.filter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.company.domain.Credential;
import org.company.domain.User;
import org.company.service.AuthService;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;


@WebFilter(filterName = "ProfileFilter", urlPatterns = "/profile")
public class ProfileFilter extends HttpFilter {

    private static final String SECRET = "something_interesting_in_this_case";

    private String jws;
    private String token;
    private String authorization;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;


        this.authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (this.authorization == null || !(this.authorization.matches("Basic .+") || this.authorization.matches("Bearer .+"))){
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }

         this.token = this.authorization.replaceAll("(Basic)|(Bearer)", "").trim();

        if (this.authorization.matches("Basic .+")){
            String decodedCredentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(this.token.getBytes()));
            String[] credentials = decodedCredentials.split(":");


            if (credentials.length != 2){
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }

            Credential credential = new Credential();
            credential.setEmail(credentials[0]);
            credential.setPassword(credentials[1]);

            AuthService authService = new AuthService();
            User user = authService.attempt(credential);


            if (credentials[0].equals(user.getEmail()) && credentials[1].equals(user.getPassword())){
                 this.jws = Jwts.builder()
                        .setIssuer("user")
                        .claim("email", credentials[0])
                        .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 2)))
                        .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SECRET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                        .compact();

                response.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", this.jws);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("token",this.jws);
                chain.doFilter(req, res);

            }else{
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }

        }else{
            try {
                Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SECRET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                        .requireIssuer("user")
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(this.token);

                chain.doFilter(req, res);

            }catch (ExpiredJwtException exp){
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                res.setContentType("text/html");
                res.getWriter().println("<h1>Token has expired, Please log in again</h1>");
                return;

            }catch (JwtException exp){
                exp.printStackTrace();
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


package org.company.filter.auth;


import org.company.utility.AuthServletRequestWrapper;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class AuthFilter extends HttpFilter {

    private String authorization;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String token = (String) session.getAttribute("token");


        AuthServletRequestWrapper authServletRequestWrapper = new AuthServletRequestWrapper(request);
        authServletRequestWrapper.putHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + token);

        System.out.println(authServletRequestWrapper.getHeader("Authorization"));

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }
}



package org.company.utility;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.util.*;

public class AuthServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String,String> headers;
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public AuthServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.headers = new HashMap<>();
        this.request = request;
    }

    public void putHeader(String key,String value){
        this.headers.put(key,value);
    }

    public String getHeader(String key){
        String headerValue = headers.get(key);
        if (headerValue != null){
            return headerValue;
        }
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(key);
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(this.headers.keySet());

        Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String n = e.nextElement();
            set.add(n);
        }

        return Collections.enumeration(set);
    }




}
```

Comment: Как токен передается заголовку?

Comment: Вы описали как это работает, точнее как вы хотите реализовать, а вопрос задать забыли.  В чем собственно проблема? Конкретно напишите что вы ожидаете и что работает не так. В том коде, что вы привели безотносительно конкретики большая проблема, что вы в объекте фильтра храните состояние. Это не будет работать. Контейнер может создать много экземпляров фильтра, может уничтожить фильтр, когда ему вздумается и данные будут потеряны. Хранить данные можно только в атрибутах запроса или в сессии.